# Why does RecyclerView not reflect progress in circle ProgressBar correctly after scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I am using a RecyclerView whose elements contain a circle ProgressBar.

progress_circle_yellow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/progress_circle_background" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="999"
            android:thicknessRatio="2.5">
            <solid android:color="@color/progress_circle_yellow"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> titleNames = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 77; i++) {
        titleNames.add("Title # "+i);
    }

     progressDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_circle_yellow);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, titleNames);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

When the RecyclerView is initially displayed, the progress is reflected correctly, but after scrolling, the progress stops being displayed correctly.
[image]
MyRecyclerViewAdapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String title = mData.get(position);
    holder.myTextView.setText(title);
    holder.progressBar.setProgress(position);
    holder.progressBar.setProgressDrawable(MainActivity.progressDrawable);
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using a static variable for the progress bar because you have the following line in the bind view holder code:

```
holder.progressBar.setProgressDrawable(MainActivity.progressDrawable);
```

This is the root of your problem since you have only one drawable for all your view holders. The seemingly random assignment of progress is just displaying the last value bound before the progress bar is drawn. The following will work better.

Remove the above line from your binding code and add the following to your view holder creation code:

```
LayerDrawable d = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(item.getContext(), R.drawable.progress_circle_yellow);
mProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(d);
```

This will give you different drawables for each view holder that can hold different progress values.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. Please tell me if I can use different ProgressDrawable for different progress?
For example:
if (mProgressBar.getProgress() > 50) {
    mProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(d);
} else 
    mProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(e);

Unfortunately, such code cannot be used in onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: Yes, that should work. I would use progress that is kept separately from the progress bar.

Comment: In which class (or method) should I use setProgressDrawable depending on the progress?

Comment: Where you bind the values in the view holder. The progress drawable is just another value that is assigned just like any other value like the text that you would apply to a _TextView_.